# Create list of intersections in QGIS

Tags: qgis, intersection

I have two layers:
(1) Postal Codes
(2) Communities

As both layers can intersect in various ways (1:n; n:1, 1:1, n:n), I want to create a list containing all communities (in layer 2) with all intersected postal codes (layer 1).

Example:

| Community 1 | Postal Code 1 |
| --- | --- |
| Community 1 | Postal Code 2 |
| Community 1 | Postal Code 3 |
| Community 2 | Postal Code 1 |
| Community 2 | Postal Code 4 |

Unfortunately, I was yet not able to find such an option directly in the tool nor on the web.

Do you have any clue how to do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to `join attributes by location`?

Comment: Hi Erik,
honestly not sure. If this would result in a new layer containing an overview of the community polygons and a new coloumn with all postal codes which are in any way overlapped. Than yes.

Comment: Hi Erik,

and if possible, I would also like to have the percentage of each overlap. Is this possible using the "join attributed by location"?

Thank you!!

Comment: How about you give it a try?

Comment: Hi Erik,
and it worked to get the "array" of each community and it's corresponding postal code. But unfortunately, it did not calculate the percentage of overlap. I also tried the "join attribute by location (summary), but there is no field which could be used to summarize since the intersection would be the new field.

Comment: What type of data are your layers?  Are they Points? Polygons?

Comment: You might look at the Overlap Analysis tool in the Vector analysis group.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Virtual layer with the query:

```sql
select row_number() over() as id, c.name, p.code
from communities c
left join postcodes p
on st_intersects(c.geometry, p.geometry)
```

Replace **communities** and **postcodes** with the names of your layers, and **name** and **code** with the names of your community fieldname and postcode code field.

[image]
[image]